# Uno WiFi Dev Ed - Example Sketch with UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1.h library by Juraj errors on compile

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi-dev-ed

Example sketch does not compile, error message
'static void WiFiClass::init()' is private within this context
IDE 1.8.13
Board Uno WiFi Dev Ed.
I have been using this board for several years uploading to Thingspeak using UnoWiFiDevEd.h using Ciao.
Now I am trying to use the UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1.h library but I can't even compile the example code below. Any suggestions?

/*
WiFiLink example: WebClient
https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-library-wifilink
*/

#include <UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1.h>
#include <WiFiLink.h>

char server[] = "arduino.cc";
boolean sendRequest = true;

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);

Serial1.begin(115200);
Serial1.resetESP();
delay(3000); //wait while WiFiLink firmware connects to WiFi with Web Panel settings

WiFi.init(&Serial1);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(10);
}
Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
printWifiStatus();
Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
if (sendRequest) {

/Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd.ino: In function 'void setup()':
UnoWiFiLink_DevEd:21:8: error: 'static void WiFiClass::init()' is private within this context
WiFi.init(&Serial1);
^~~~
In file included from /Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd.ino:7:0:
/Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WiFi_Link/src/WiFiLink.h:44:17: note: declared private here
static void init();
^~~~
UnoWiFiLink_DevEd:21:21: error: no matching function for call to 'WiFiClass::init(UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1*)'
WiFi.init(&Serial1);
^
In file included from /Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd/UnoWiFiLink_DevEd.ino:7:0:
/Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WiFi_Link/src/WiFiLink.h:44:17: note: candidate: static void WiFiClass::init()
static void init();
^~~~
/Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WiFi_Link/src/WiFiLink.h:44:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
Using library Uno_WiFi_Developer_Edition_Serial1 at version 1.0.4 in folder: /Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Uno_WiFi_Developer_Edition_Serial1
Using library WiFi_Link at version 1.0.1 in folder: /Users/mack/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WiFi_Link
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: /private/var/folders/5v/dc3kh_4136g2j560dgjg3vww0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E151A1AA-2F37-45B4-9B3C-A69070247D9C/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire
exit status 1
'static void WiFiClass::init()' is private within this context

Comment: @Juraj *ping* - sounds like one for you...

Comment: you have the Library Manager version of the WiFiLink library. it doesn't allow to specify a Serial interface and has SC converter library included. use the version from the GitHub repo you linked. did you change the firmware?

Comment: it is documented here: https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-library-wifilink#install-this-library